# Create a list of webform submissions sorted and searchable by data in user submitted form fields

Tags: views, webforms

I am using Webform 6.x on Drupal 8.
I would like to create a list of submissions that are sorted and searchable by the user entered data within the submissions. I am able to generate a list of of the submissions but I'm unable to compare, sort, or view the field data within the form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with views.

1. Create a view set to show 'Webform Submissions'
2. Under advanced click 'Add' next to relationships.
3. Select the form you want the submissions for in 'Webform Node'
4. Select the field you want to sort/search by in 'Component Data'
5. Select 'Relate using node and Component ID'
6. Add as many relationships as you want if you want to sort/search by
   more fields.
7. Add Webform Submission Data:Value in the fields section and select
   the webform node and the component data.
8. Add Webform submission data: Data field in Filter Criteria. Select
   the relationship of the field you want to sort/search by and expose
   the filter if you want to allow it to be searchable.

I was looking at a Drupal 7 instance when preparing this answer so the naming might be slightly different but it should work the same in 8.

Comment: Thank you, Matt, I'll try that and let you know!

Comment: Dear Matt, when creating a view showing Webform submissions in Drupal 8, There is no "Webform Node" in Relationship, there is no "Component Data', so nothing to relate. Am I missing a component/library/module?